# What is the equivalent of "git rebase --onto commit-id^ commit-id" in LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: c#, .net, git, libgit2sharp

I want execute something like "git rebase --onto commit-id^ commit-id" in LibGit2Sharp to delete a commit. What I have found is a method `Repository.Rebase.Start`, but it accept `Branch`, not `Commit`. Is there any other way to do what I want?